# How to add text inside HTML5 Canvas Pushpins - BingMap

Tags: dictionary, bing-maps, pushpin

I am following bing map concave example from this link

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript/

I am wondering if it is possible to add a text inside concave pushpin? I have tried with

```
context.font = "15px Arial";
context.fillText("33", 5, 50);
```

but it shows text underneath the pin not inside the pin.

I can add text to normal push pin but not sure if it is possible with concave;

```
var offset = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5); 
var pushpinOptions = { text : '1', visible: true, textOffset: offset};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the text on the canvas. The HTML5 canvas pushpin class overrides the default template for pushpins and replaces it with an HTML5 canvas. Anything you want to display on the pushpin has to be drawn on the canvas. Here is a simple example:

```
context.font = "30px Arial";
context.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```